# Is $R/N(R)$ a faithfully flat $R$-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

I'm studying recently faithfully flat modules and I'd like to know the following:

> Is $R/N$ faithfully flat as $R$-module, where $R$ is a commutative ring with unit and $N$ is the ideal of nilpotent elements of $R$?

Comment: Have you tried to check flatness before asking?

Answer (score 14):

If $I\subset R$ is an arbitrary  ideal, then $R/I$ can only be flat if $I=I^2$ :  this follows from tensoring  the exact sequence $0\to I\to R$ by $R/I$ and getting the exact sequence $0\to I\otimes _R R/I=I/I^2\stackrel {0}{\to} R/I$.

This is a tool for proving that many quotients of a ring  are not flat over the ring:
 For example if $k$ is a field, then  the ring $R=k[\epsilon]=k[T]/(T^2)$ has as nilpotents $N=(\epsilon)$, and since $(\epsilon)^2=(0)\neq (\epsilon)$, the quotient $R/N$ is not flat over $R$, which answers your question negatively (we don't have flatness of $R/N$ over $R$, let alone faithful flatness).

Comment: To a friend: everybody makes mistakes! Grothendieck's erroneous statement about the Brauer group was the basis of at least one masters thesis and several research articles!

Comment: Faithfully flat = flat and surjective on spectra, but $\mathrm{Spec}(R/N) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is a homeomorphism. So actually here all comes down to the failure of flatness.

Comment: Dear Georges, I am curious about Grothendieck's mistake.

Comment: I wonder whether the condition $I=I^2$ (with $I=N(R)$) is sufficient for the flatness ? Should ask separately the question ?

Comment: Dear Cantlog, the formula (7) page 74 in Grothendieck's *Le groupe de Brauer II* is incorrect if the scheme has more than one singularity. The quoted article is in the book *Dix exposés sur la cohomologie des schémas*. And you could certainly ask a separate question about $I=I^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Sorry for boring you with, but what is wrong in this formula ? There are many definitions, so it is little hard for me to understand quickly.

Comment: Dear @Cantlog, have a look at the article *Nontrivial, Locally Trivial Azumaya Algebras* by
F. R. DEMEYER and T. J. FORD, in Contemp. Math. 124 (1992)

Comment: Thanks Georges! I will get the article and have a look.

Comment: Dear @Cantlog: another notorious mistake by Grothendieck (and many others) is his definition of rational function, which doesn't make sense: [here](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?rid=ensmat-001:1979:25%3a:375&id=&id2=&id3=) is Kleiman's celebrated article explaining the error.

Comment: I knew this one and the mistake is easy to understand (the definition doesn't even give a presheaf). But I don't know other mistakes in EGA.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: The mistake in Brauer II seems to be  a confusion of Pic(X) with Cl(X), right ?