# Is $R/I$ flat over $R$ when $I$ is the nilradical of $R$ and $I=I^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This is a flowup of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487214/). To be precise, let $R$ is a commutative unitary ring with nilradical $I$. In the above URL, it is proved that if $R/I$ is a flat $R$-module, then $I=I^2$.

My question is whether the converse holds in general. Thanks !

Comment: If $I$ is finitely generated, yes, because by Nakayama $I=0$.

Comment: One can also work in the case $I$ is finitely generated but not necessarily $\sqrt R$. Assuming $I^2=I$, use the determinant trick to prove that $I=(e)$ for an idempotent $e$, and then it easily follows that $R/I$ is flat.

Comment: Dear Martin and @KarlKronenfeld, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in general, no.

Let $R$ be a zero dimensional local ring, and suppose that its maximal ideal $I$
satisfies $I^2 = I$.  Then $R/I$ is flat over $R$ only if $I = 0$.  (See [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/66794/).)

E.g. if $S$ is a one-dimensional local domain with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m $ such that $\mathfrak m^2 = \mathfrak m$
and $x \in \mathfrak m$ is non-zero, then $R := S/(x)$ is a zero-dimensional local ring whose maximal ideal $I$ satifies $I^2 = I$.

E.g. Let $S = \overline{\mathbb Z}_p$ denote the integral closure of $\mathbb Z_p$ in $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$, and take $s = p$.  Then $R = \overline{\mathbb Z}_p/(p)$ gives a concrete example.