# Is R/m a flat R-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, flatness

Let $(R,\frak m)$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring.
Is $R/\frak m$ a flat $R$-module?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/487240/121097) you can learn that if $R/\mathfrak m$ is $R$-flat then $\mathfrak m=\mathfrak m^2$. Since $\mathfrak m$ is finitely generated it must be generated by an idempotent, that is, $\mathfrak m=(0)$ so $R$ is a field.