# Flatness of $A=F[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\langle f_1,\dots,f_k \rangle$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, jacobian, flatness

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100323/flatness-criterion-for-a-finite-type-algebra-based-on-the-jacobian) question asks for a proof of the following fact:
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f_1,\dots,f_k\in R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ polynomials such that the Jacobian $J=(\partial f_{j}/\partial x_i)_{i,j}$ has total rank in every residue field $k(P)$ for $P\in\text{Spec}(R)$
Then the following $R$-algebra is flat $$A=R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_k).$$

I am not sure if I understand it correctly, so I ask:

> **Question 1:** Is it true that if we take $R=F$ a field (of characteristic zero), $k=n$, 
>   and the Jacobian of $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ is a non-zero scalar,
>   then the claim says that $$A=F[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_n).$$
>   is flat as an $F$-module? (or as an $F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$-module?)

**EDIT:** Actually, what I really wish to ask is:

> **Question 2:** Is the quoted result dealing with $k \leq n$ only,
>   or is it dealing with $k > n$ also?

I am confused: On the one hand, no restriction on $\{k,n\}$ is mentioned in the quoted question, but on the other hand, the two references [i](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00SV) [ii](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00T7) in its comment seem to deal with $k \leq n$ (if I am not wrong).

**Examples for question 2** (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540123/a-flatness-of-fracb-langle-b-i-rangle-a-subseteq-b-ab-implies/3540131#3540131) question):

**(1)** $f_1=x^2+y,f_2=y$, $R=k[x]$, $n=1$.
$\frac{k[x][y]}{\langle x^2+y,y \rangle}= \frac{k[x]}{\langle x^2 \rangle}$ is not flat over $k[x]$, by the result quoted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794117/flatness-of-quotient-rings).
However, the it is not possible to apply the above result (assuming that $k > n$ is ok), since the Jacobian is the one-row matrix $(1 1)$ (partial derivatives of $f_1,f_2$ with respect to $y$), so the rank is one (the rank is not total= not equals two).

**(2)** $f_1=x^2+y,f_2=x$, $R=k[x]$, $n=1$.
$\frac{k[x][y]}{\langle x^2+y,x \rangle}= \frac{k[x,y]}{\langle x,y \rangle}=k$.
Actually, it is not possible to apply the above result (assuming that $k > n$ is ok), since the Jacobian is the one-row matrix $(1 0)$ (partial derivatives of $f_1,f_2$ with respect to $y$), so the rank is one (the rank is not total= not equals two).

**(3)!!!** $f_1=x+y^2,f_2=y+x+y^2$, $R=k[x]$, $n=1$. Again, $\frac{k[x][y]}{\langle x+y^2,y+x+y^2 \rangle}= \frac{k[x,y]}{\langle x,y \rangle}=k$. 
Here the Jacobian is the one-row matrix $(2y, 1+2y)$ (partial derivatives of $f_1,f_2$ with respect to $y$), and the rank is total (two).
It seems that this example shows that it is NOT possible to take $k > n$, since $k$ is not a flat $k[x]$-module, by the flatness criterion presented in the first answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259551/how-to-show-fraction-field-is-flat-without-localization) question, with the action of $k[x]$ on $k$ defined as follows: $x \lambda=0$, for all $\lambda \in k$, and scalars are computed as ususal, in $k$.

**Remarks:**
(1) [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208/can-a-quotient-ring-r-j-ever-be-flat-over-r) MO question seems relevant.
(2) [This](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1972-171-00/S0002-9947-1972-0306176-6/S0002-9947-1972-0306176-6.pdf) paper seems relevant, but it deals with $n=1$ and instead of taking $(f_1)$ it takes $I$ and shows that it must be a principal ideal. (We can take $R=k[y]$ and then deal with $k[y][x]$. But it is not possible to apply the stronger results, since $R$ is required to be quasi-local).

Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem specifies "R-algebra" so it implies "R-flat"

Comment: @BrianMoehring, thank you (this is what I thought). So in particular, if $p,q \in k[x,y]$ satisfy $p_xq_y-p_yq_x=1$, then $\frac{k[x,y]}{(p,q)}$ is flat over $k$. Can we say something 'interesting' about such ideal $(p,q)$?

Comment: Every module is flat (in fact free) over a field. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @metalspringpro, thank you for your comment. You are not misunderstanding my question. (I see now that I have forgotten to add the condition that the Jacobian of $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ is a non-zero scalar, so the Jacobi matrix has total rank).

Comment: @user237522 Such a condition is not needed, if $F$ is a field, every $F$-module is free, hence flat.  In particular, $F[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_k)$ is flat over $F$ regardless of what the $f_i$ are.

Comment: @metalspringpro, oh, yes, you are right.  (Please, could you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536848/flatness-of-frackx-yi-over-kx-and-over-ky)

Comment: @metalspringpro, please, I have now edited my above question; any new comments are welcome.